# Xcode provisioning profiles order

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, code-signing, provisioning-profile

Feels like a silly question but i'm gonna try anyway cause it's really bugging me...

Can i control the provisioning profiles order?

I have a lot of projects of various clients, which means a very large list of provisioning profiles which are sorted by date.

[image]

Is there a way of making them sorted by name/project?

Answer (score 1):

I think no.

To make things simpler, I am, for instance, keep locally only profiles for project (or two) I'm working on right now. You could always download required and delete useless

Go to **Xcode preferences -> Accounts -> choose correct account -> View details**

right click on unused profile

**-> move to trash**